# GRASS GIS: red square around node topology information?

Tags: grass-gis

I've been using GRASS since 2005, but I cannot find an explanation to the square boxes that appear around the nodes of a lines layers, when I display topological informations on the map.

[image]

I thought they could indicate errors, but my layer appear to be topologically ok. Someone has told that those square lines refer to bboxes, but it doesn't convince me. Nodes' BBOXes? I have many layers and I only see them on this one...

Any GRASS user/dev out?

Giovanni

Answer (score 1):

Since this was also asked in various mailing lists, here just the link to the answer:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2013-April/067755.html